# Cant write any data into my SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
private void comboBox9_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finish_day = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox9.Text);      
    }
    private void comboBox10_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finish_month = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox10.Text);
    }
    private void comboBox11_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finfish_year = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox11.Text);
    }

    private void comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        begin_year = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox6.Text);
    }

    private void comboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        begin_month = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox7.Text);
    }

    private void comboBox8_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        begin_day = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox8.Text);
    }
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // important
        from_bs_2 += serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(showdata));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
    private void showdata(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int changdu = from_bs_2.Length;
        if (changdu > 50)
        {
            chushihua++;
            string fro;
            string[] parm = new string[6];
            textBox1.Text += from_bs_2;
            fro = from_bs_2;
            parm = fro.Split('\n');
            string path = "C:\\Users\\COM\\Desktop\\data_logging.txt";

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

            for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++)
            {
                string[] zhongjian = new string[23];
                zhongjian = parm[a].Split(';');
                //  textBox1.Text += zhongjian;
                for (int keai = 0; keai < 23; keai++)
                {
                    current[a, keai] = Convert.ToDouble(zhongjian[keai]);
                    sw.Write(current[a, keai]); sw.Write(';');


                }
                sw.WriteLine('/');
            }
            string[] zhongjian_2 = new string[23];
            zhongjian_2 = parm[5].Split(';');
            for (int m = 0; m < 23; m++) // 
            {
                volatge[m] = Convert.ToDouble(zhongjian_2[m]);
                sw.Write(volatge[m]); sw.Write(';');
            }
            sw.WriteLine('/');

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;  //strong text

            int y = dt.Year;      //
            int yue = dt.Month;     //
            int d = dt.Day;       //
            int h = dt.Hour;      //
            int n = dt.Minute;    //  
            textBox1.Text += y;
            textBox1.Text += "-";
            textBox1.Text += yue;
            textBox1.Text += "-";
            textBox1.Text += d;
            textBox1.Text += "-";
            textBox1.Text += h;
            textBox1.Text += ":";
            textBox1.Text += n;

            textBox1.Text += "-";
            textBox1.Text += "data logging times";
            textBox1.Text += chushihua;


            sw.Write(y); sw.Write("-"); sw.Write(yue); sw.Write("-"); sw.Write(d);
            sw.Write("-"); sw.Write(h); sw.Write(":"); sw.Write(n); sw.WriteLine('/');
            sw.Close();
            fs.Close();
            //////////////////time/////////////////////////////



            string info = "INSERT INTO Logging_Data_2 (Time,Number,Power1,Power2,Power3,Power4,Power5,Power6,Power7,Power8,Power9,Power10,Power11,Power,Power12,Power13,Power14,Power15,Power16,Power17,Power18,Power19,Power20,Power21,Power22,Power23) values ('a',1,current[0, 0],current[0, 1],current[0, 2],current[0, 3],current[0, 4],current[0, 5],current[0, 6],current[0, 7],current[0, 8],current[0, 9],current[0, 10],current[0, 11],current[0, 12],current[0, 13],current[0, 14],current[0, 15],current[0, 16],current[0, 17],current[0, 18],current[0, 19],current[0, 20],current[0, 21],current[0, 22])";
            using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=logging_data.db"))
            {
              //  connection.Open();
              //  using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            //    {
                    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(connection))
                    {
                       connection.Open();
                       command.CommandText = info;
                     //*emphasized text*command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                      }
                 //    transaction.Commit();
              //  }
            }


            from_bs_2 = "";
            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 1500)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }


        }
```

I am wirting a super simple file, get the data from arduino though serial ports, and than if i get data, first i log them in a txt file, and then I need to send them into a database for future calculation. therefore I installed the SQLite, and write caode in this, but when i test it, I can log data to txt fime, but nothing in my database.

I set up a database named logging_data, and the table is Logging_data_2, when I find I cant log any data to database, i just let the time be 'a', number be 1,but it still doesnt work. ask for help, thankyou!

Comment: What error are you getting?  If nor your getting one build in error trapping into your code and get the error.  There could be many reasons it is not working.

Comment: you never issued any code to the sql server.. You made a connection set a command and then closed the connection

Comment: There is no error, the code works well, but cant log any data to my data station

Comment: @BugFinder, I think I write the info string, why I didnt issued any code? can you teach me how to wirte it? thankyou

Comment: Look at the bit you connect to the database, you commented out the bit that ran the command